# MRTG with RRDTool have nothings show up

Tags: gps, monitoring, ntp, rrdtool, mrtg

I was built NTP server with my raspi and then I use MRTG to  monitor OFFSET and JITTER and It's work correctly.
I was just +1000 at the offset values before for Negative values can show up.
Now I want to change the graph that can plot the negative values, so I decided to use MRTG with RRDTool and follow the guide https://weberblog.net/basic-ntp-server-monitoring/?fbclid=IwAR3iV_rdwQK95axV8JWSmtBub9bhHtGbn9SGtLHSfSotsRXEVkO8YLuqZFM but it's doesn't work.
Here's my mrtg.cfg

```
WorkDir: /var/www/html/mrtg 
LogFormat: rrdtool
```

```
Target[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: `ntpq -c rv ip | grep offset | sed s/.*$
MaxBytes[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: 100000
Title[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Offset µs -- ntp2-gps
Options[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: gauge
Colours[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: DARKPURPLE#7608AA, Blue#0000FF, BLACK#000000, Purple#FF00FF
YLegend[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Offset in microseconds (µs)
Legend1[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Offset
Legend3[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Peak Offset
LegendI[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Offset:
ShortLegend[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: µs
PageTop[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: OFFSET MONITOR
routers.cgi*Options[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: fixunit nototal noo
routers.cgi*ShortDesc[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: Offset µs ntp2-gps
routers.cgi*Icon[ntp2-gps-offset-us]: graph-sm.gif


Target[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: `ntpq -c rv ip | grep sys_jitter | sed $
MaxBytes[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: 100000
Title[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Jitter µs -- ntp2-gps
Options[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: gauge
Colours[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: TURQUOISE#00CCCC, Blue#0000FF, DARKTURQUOISE#377D77, Purple#FF00FF
YLegend[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Jitter in microseconds (µs)
Legend1[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Jitter
Legend3[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Peak Jitter
LegendI[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Jitter:
PageTop[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: <H1>JITTER MONITOR</H1>
ShortLegend[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: µs
routers.cgi*Options[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: fixunit nototal noo
routers.cgi*ShortDesc[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: Jitter µs ntp2-gps
routers.cgi*Icon[ntp2-gps-jitter-us]: link-sm.gif
```

Here's my result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuCfv.png)

Comment: You should really use a factor of 0.00001 and then let mrtg/routers take care of displaying the correct units

Answer (score 0):

When MRTG creates an RRD file, the max/min range for the DS is set to be from 0 to MaxBytes.  Thus, in order to allow negative values (such as for offset) to be stored, you need to subsequently tune the RRD file to allow this.  Unfortunately Tobi never added a MinBytes setting!

This will set the 'in' value on targetname.rrd to allow a minimum of -1000000

```
rrdtool tune targetname.rrd --minimum ds0:-1000000
```

Once you have done this, then it should be able to store negative values.